# Http call to springboot application is not hitting from angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, restful-url

I have created a service class like this,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class PacsService {

  private url: string = "http://localhost:8888/";

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getPacs(){
    return this.http.get(this.url+"pacs/getAll")
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getPac(id){
    return this.http.get(this.getPacUrl(id))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  addPac(pac){
    return this.http.post(this.url+"pacs/create", pac)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  updatePac(pac){
    return this.http.put(this.url+"pacs/update", pac)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  deletePac(id){      
    return this.http.delete(this.url+"pacs/delete/"+id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  getDccbBranches()
  {
    return this.http.get(this.url+"dccbBranch/getAll")
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  private getPacUrl(id){
    return this.url + "pacs/getById/" + id;
  }
}
```

no method hits the springboot application. But the springboot application works fine .I have checked it by hitting through browser but through the angular application it is not able to.

what i did is,

i started the springboot application in the debug mode and run the angular application also in debug mode. but its not hitting the debug point in springboot application.

can someone please help ?

Note: working with angular 5 in visual studio code.

The component looks like this,

```
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  addressForm: FormGroup;
  address: Address;
  contactInfo: ContactInfo;
  pacs: Pacs;
  transportization: Transportization;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private pacsService: PacsService,
    private contactInfoService: ContactInfoService,
    private addressService: AddressService,
    private transportizationService: TransportizationService) {

      this.pacs=new Pacs();
      this.contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
      this.address = new Address();
      this.transportization = new Transportization();
}

save() {

    console.log('in Save button of Address Component...');
    var result;



    if (this.pacs.id){
      console.log('Inside update pac of Address component');
      result = this.pacsService.updatePac(this.pacs);
    } else {
      console.log('Inside add pac of Address component');
      //result = this.pacsService.addPac(this.pacs);
      this.pacsService.getPacs();
    }
    if(result != null) {
      console.log('Data Inserted in Pacs table', );
    }
    else {
      console.log("Data not Inserted in Pacs table");
    }
```

address.module.ts contains,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule }  from '@angular/http';

import { AddressComponent } from './address.component';
import { AddressService } from './shared/addressService/address.service';
import { ContactInfoService } from './shared/contactService/contactInfo.service';
import { PacsService } from './shared/pacsService/pacs.service';
import { TransportizationService } from './shared/transportizationService/transportization.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AddressComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AddressComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AddressService,
    ContactInfoService,
    PacsService,
    TransportizationService
  ]
})
export class addressModule { }
```

Comment: do you subscribe to any of these methods? `this.pacsService.getPac(id).subscribe(....)`?

Comment: make sure you are importing header in your component .... `import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';` ... If everything else is ok then this might be the issue

Comment: you mean in the component class ?...if its then no..i called the service method directly this.pacsService.getPacs()

Comment: in the componet files where you call these methods, do you do a subscribe on the end?

Comment: @AluanHaddad i didnt mention data binding?

Comment: also, if you're using angular 5, you should be using HttpClient hot Http as its deprecated in ng5

Comment: @Aakriti.G : i have added headers but it did not work..

Comment: yes, subscribe is required, without it the call is only defined but never called

Comment: @AluanHaddad no, im not. if the function is called like so `this.pacsService.getPacs()` (like @ChandraMouli said) then he needs to do a `.subscribe()` to actually do the call instead of just declaring it

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I am 100% aware that that is a very common mistake. However, you can also databind directly to a service method, like `<i *ngIf="service.getPacs() | async">` which also makes the observable hot.

Comment: @AluanHaddad well if you think thats the correct answer, why not post an answer?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon there is no basis to answer. We would need to see the consuming code to determine it. I am also _not_ saying I am write and you are wrong. I am saying that we cannot say for certain that `subscribe` is required. This is a bad question with insufficient information and no additional information was added as requested.

Comment: @AluanHaddad we have seen the consuming code, check the 3rd comment on the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165636/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: i did it so we arent clogging this question's comments

Comment: i will surely add extra data..wait a min..i am trying out something

Answer (score 1):

The `.map()` isn't firing the http request, it is a callback that will be called before returning to the initial call.

Try doing .subscribe(result=>{this.localDataVariable = result}) or .toPromise().then(result=>{this.localDataVariable = result})

Using your code, try the following:

```
if (this.pacs.id){
    console.log('Inside update pac of Address component');
    this.pacsService.updatePac(this.pacs)
        .subscribe(
            res => result = res,
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("Completed Call"),
        );
} else {
      console.log('Inside add pac of Address component');
      //result = this.pacsService.addPac(this.pacs);
      this.pacsService.getPacs()
        .subscribe(
            res => result = res,
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("Completed Call"),
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding subscribe to the service request worked.

like this,
this.pacsService.addPac(this.pacs).subscribe(data => this.pacs = data);

Answer (score -1):

Http *rxjs* request return an **Observable** Object, correct ways to manage this inside your Service is:

```
get(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url)
}
```

where T is the Object returned by your request.

In your **component** call the **service** in this way:

```
this.service.get().subscribe(value => this.variable = value)
```

Where **service** is the class *injected* in the constructor:

```
constructor(private service: Service) {}
```

More info at https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: that wouldnt work for a json response, a json response requires the http call to have a `.map(res => res.json())` on the end of it